# multiple use of cellfun

Tags: arrays, matlab, simulink

Using the command `get_param(maskBlock,'MaskVariables')`, I get a string that look like this :

```
'AB=@1;AC=@2;AD=@3;AE=@4;..AZ=@26;'
```

I wanted to change the numbers and add 1 to them in order to get :

```
'AB=@2;AC=@3;AD=@4;AE=@5;..AZ=@27;'
```

Here what i have coded :

```
strSplit = regexp(theStringFromGetParam , ';', 'split')'; % split the string at the ; to get multiple strings
str1 = cellfun(@(x) str2double(regexp(x,'(\d+)','tokens','once'))+1, strSplit, 'UniformOutput', false); % cell containing the last numbers
str2 = cellfun(@(x) regexp(x,'(\w+)(\W+)','tokens','once'), strSplit, 'UniformOutput', false); % cell containing everything that is not a number
str3 = cellfun(@(x) strcat(x{1}, x{2}), str2, 'UniformOutput', false); % join the two parts from the line above
str4 = cellfun(@(x,y) strcat(x,num2str(y)), str3, str1, 'UniformOutput', false); % join the number numbers with the "letters=@"
```

It works, but I'm almost certain that there is a better way to do this. Anyone could help me find a better way than using 4 times the command `cellfun`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's a one-liner:

```
str = 'AB=@1;AC=@2;AD=@3;AE=@4;AZ=@26;';
regexprep(str,'(?<=@)(\d+)','${sprintf(''%d'',str2double($1)+1)}')
```

The **match** is easy: at any point in the string, look back for an `@`, if found then match onwards one or more consecutive digits and capture into a token.

The **replacement**: `str2double()` the captured token, add `1` and convert back to an integer. The command is executed with the dynamic expression `'${command}'`.

Comment: Very nice! I'll try to understand everything (other answer as well) before accepting the final answer.

Answer (score 3):

I have an answer without using cellfun but using tokens instead:

```
%the given string
str = 'AB=@1;AC=@2;AD=@3;AE=@4;..AZ=@26;';
%find the numbers using tokens
regex = '=@(\d+);';
%dynamic replacement - take the token, convert it to a number - add 1 - and
%convert it back to a string
replace = '=@${num2str(str2num($1)+1)};';
%here is your result - replace all found numbers with the replace string
regexprep(str, regexp, replace)
```

Comment: I haven't seen yours at first! Same in spirit, although the str2num and num2str damages performance.

Comment: nice answer. However, it is unwise to use `regexp` as a variable name: it is a built-in function name!

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
num = regexp( theStringFromGetParam, '@(\d+);', 'tokens' ); % get the numbers
num = cellfun( @(x) str2double(x), num ); % convert to numbers
frmt = regexprep( theStringFromGetParam, '@(\d+);', '@%%d;' );
sprintf( frmt, num ); % print the updated numbers into the format string.
```

Comment: I like this answer as well! Going to be difficult to make my choice!

Comment: @m_power I'd go with Oleg's answer

Answer (score 0):

Woops, I started writing this last night before I left work and forgot to finish it. Just an example using textscan rather than regexp.

```
ManyCells=textscan(theStringFromGetParam,'%s%d', 'delimiter','@;');
S=arrayfun(@(x) sprintf('%s@%d;',ManyCells{1}{x},1+ManyCells{2}(x)),1:length(ManyCells{1}),'uniformoutput',false)
NewString=cat(2,S{:});
```

I tried playing around with indexing and cellfun to dispose of the arrayfun but couldn't work it out; any ideas anybody?